# Ruby form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails.
I have a form say form1.On clicking the submit button this form  should take me to another form with the parameters passed.Please let me know how to do it and also how to access the form1 parameters in form2.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a multistep form, check out: http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

The basic concept is that you will have to set the url to post to in your form tag (the default is a create or update action).  Once in your new controller action, your previous form is available in the params hash.  Without more details on your question, we can't provide better details.